How to NDSolve stiff ODE?
I want to solve this ODE.
   k = 10^13;
   H = 10^-5;
    \[Chi][z_] := \[Pi]/4 + ArcTan[3/10 (34 - H*z)];
    \[ScriptA][z_] := E^(H*z);
  s = NDSolve[
  {A''[t] + ((\[ScriptA]'[t]/\[ScriptA][t] - 2 (I*k)/\[ScriptA][t])*
        A'[t] + 20*k/\[ScriptA][t]*\[Chi]'[t] A[t]) == 0, A[0] == 1, 
   A'[0] == 0},
  {A[t], A'[t], A''[t]}, {t, 0, 65*10^5}]

I tried below, but failed:







Thanks for your all suggestions!

This question is much easier than your previous one. Just set a small enough MaxStepSize:
k = 10^13;
H = 1/10^5;
χ[z_] := π/4 + ArcTan[3/10 (34 - H z)];
\[ScriptA][z_] := E^(H z);
tend = 65 10^5;
sol = NDSolveValue[{A''[
       t] + ((\[ScriptA]'[t]/\[ScriptA][t] - 
           2 (I k)/\[ScriptA][t]) A'[t] + 
        20*k/\[ScriptA][t] χ'[t] A[t]) == 0, A[0] == 1, 
    A'[0] == 0}, A, {t, 0, tend}, MaxStepSize -> 10^3];

ReImPlot[sol[t], {t, 0, tend}]


Rule of thumb:

The default ODE solver of NDSolve is quite robust and should always be the last thing to check.

If one finally begins checking the ODE solver, the MaxStepSize is the first thing to adjust.

If one finally begins checking the ODE solver, the method for time integration is the last thing to adjust.



This ODE is stiff, so I choose  method-stiffnessswitching  seems reasonable and it  fits this type equation. Well, I admit Mathematica's black box often makes me curious.
